# Looping over dynamic JSON in a specific way

Tags: javascript, json, loops, dynamic

I currently have this JSON file

```
{   
"name": "Connor Atherton",
"course": "Combined Sciences",

"modules" : {

    "MATH210": 
    {
        "weekly": 65,
        "weekly2": 76,
        "exam": 80
    },

    "MATH215": {
        "weekly": 65,
        "exam": 80
    },

    "MATH220": {
        "weekly": 65,
        "exam": 80
    },

    "MATH225": {
        "weekly": 65,
        "weekly2": 98,
        "exam": 80
    },

    "SCC210": {
        "weekly": 65,
        "exam": 80
    },

    "SCC204": {
        "weekly": 65,
        "exam": 80
    }

}

}
```

As you can see in each module there could be a different number of properties which will be retrieved dynamically.

I am currently looping over each module like this

```
$.each(json.modules, function(i, item) {
    console.log(i + " " + item.exam);
});
```

However this won't work for all the modules since they can all have a different number of properties.

I have been trying to loop over each module's properties with for loops but I can't quite get it to work. I figured I should use

```
item.length
```

somewhere in the loop but I'm not sure.

Do you have any idea how I could loop over each module if each one has a different number of properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
$.each(json.modules, function(i, item) {
    for (var key in item){
        // output, to example: "exam = 80"
        console.log(key + ' = ' + item[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah that did it thanks, I had var item in i instead of key in item!